# Is there a site where I could get a high resolution global annual temperature map?

Tags: climate, temperature

I'm exploring different places on the countryside and would like to compare their different annual temperatures. The options that I've seen are either too coarse (NASA, NOAA, arcgis (free online version)) or I need to pay (open weather)

It seems google earth had this feature at some point with an alliance with the Weather Company https://medium.com/google-earth/temperature-radar-wind-speed-explore-weather-data-in-google-earth-a7610e8c8eae

Comment: you should check ERA5 by ECMWF: https://www.ecmwf.int/en/forecasts/datasets/reanalysis-datasets/era5